# WebAdi integrator with custom parameter to filter LoV returns error "An exception occurred trying to map a column."

Tags: sql, oracle, integrator

In Oracle EBS R12.2.5 I created a custom WebAdi integrator. 
I have a field 'Supplier Number' and integrator parameter Supplier Type. 
I want to filter Supplier number field based on the supplier type value before creating the document. For this purpose i specify the Supplier Number as LoV and i add the parameter value to its where clause. 
When i create the document, i'm able to filter the supplier number filter correctly, but when i hit Upload button i get below error:
"An exception occurred trying to map a column."

If I remove the parameter from the where clause all is fine.

Bne.log file shows this error:

4/6/17 8:30 PM [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneAsyncUploadPage.renderPage+Error+trying+to+check+whether+the+job+will+be+importing.
4/6/17 8:30 PM [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneAsyncUploadPage.renderPage+Parameter+value+is+not+a+Boolean.
4/6/17 8:31 PM [STUCK] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneBaseSQL.executeQuery%3A+Exception+while+running+query.++Error+Code%3A+17041%2C+Message%3A+Missing+IN+or+OUT+parameter+at+index%3A%3A+3
4/6/17 8:31 PM [STUCK] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneBaseSQL.executeQuery%3A+Query%3A+SELECT+ss.vendor_site_id%2Cs.segment1%2Cvendor_name%2C+vendor_site_code+FROM+ap_suppliers+s%2C+ap_supplier_sites_all+ss%2C+xxpri_org_access+a+WHERE+s.vendor_id+%3D+ss.vendor_id+and+ss.org_id+%3D+a.organization_id++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI188++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI189++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI190++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI191++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI192++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI193++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI194++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI195++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI196++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI197++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI198++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI199++AND+UPPER(s.segment1)+LIKE+%3ABNESQLCRI200++ORDER+BY+2%2C3%2C4
4/6/17 8:31 PM [STUCK] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneBaseSQL.executeQuery%3A+Args+%3A+%25%25%2C+%25%25
4/6/17 8:31 PM [STUCK] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneBaseSQL.executeQuery%3A+Stack+trace%3A+java.sql.SQLException%3A+Missing+IN+or+OUT+parameter+at+index%3A%3A+3%0A%09at+oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java%3A1899)%0A%09at+oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java%3A3764)%0A%09at+oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java%3A3823)%0A%09at+oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java%3A1671)%0A%09at+weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java%3A135)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.utilities.sql.BneBaseSQL.executeQuery(BneBaseSQL.java%3A1535)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.utilities.sql.BneBaseSQL.getRS(BneBaseSQL.java%3A696)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.webui.control.BneTableUIControl.populateDataSQL(BneTableUIControl.java%3A1377)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.webui.control.BneTableUIControl.populateData(BneTableUIControl.java%3A1184)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.webui.control.BneTableUIControl.createNodes(BneTableUIControl.java%3A1965)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.webui.control.BneLOVUIControl.createNodes(BneLOVUIControl.java%3A766)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.integrator.component.BneAbstractListOfValues.createPage(BneAbstractListOfValues.java%3A736)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.integrator.component.BneAbstractListOfValues.handleComponent(BneAbstractListOfValues.java%3A580)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.integrator.component.BneComponentService.executeComponent(BneComponentService.java%3A512)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.integrator.component.BneComponentService.handleRequest(BneComponentService.java%3A312)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.framework.BneBajaServlet.doRequest(BneBajaServlet.java%3A313)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.framework.BneBaseServlet.doPost(BneBaseServlet.java%3A98)%0A%09at+javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java%3A727)%0A%09at+javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java%3A820)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper%24ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java%3A227)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java%3A125)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java%3A301)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java%3A26)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java%3A60)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.jtf.cabo.interceptor.JTFWrapperFilter.doFilter(JTFWrapperFilter.java%3A149)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java%3A60)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.jtf.base.session.ReleaseResFilter.doFilter(Unknown+Source)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java%3A60)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.fnd.security.AppsServletFilter.doFilter(AppsServletFilter.java%3A432)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java%3A60)%0A%09at+oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter%241.run(JpsAbsFilter.java%3A138)%0A%09at+java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java%3A456)%0A%09at+oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java%3A324)%0A%09at+oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java%3A464)%0A%09at+oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java%3A121)%0A%09at+oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java%3A211)%0A%09at+oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java%3A71)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java%3A60)%0A%09at+oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java%3A163)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java%3A60)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext%24ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java%3A3748)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext%24ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java%3A3714)%0A%09at+weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java%3A321)%0A%09at+weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java%3A120)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java%3A2283)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java%3A2182)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java%3A1499)%0A%09at+weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java%3A263)%0A%09at+weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java%3A221)%0A
4/6/17 8:31 PM [STUCK] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneUIXUtils.createErrorPageNodes()%3A+Exception+Name%3A+oracle.apps.bne.exception.BneSQLException
4/6/17 8:31 PM [STUCK] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneUIXUtils.createErrorPageNodes()%3A+Message+Text%3A+Cannot+execute+SQL+Statement.
4/6/17 8:31 PM [STUCK] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneUIXUtils.createErrorPageNodes()%3A+Nested+Message%3A+Missing+IN+or+OUT+parameter+at+index%3A%3A+3
4/6/17 8:31 PM [STUCK] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneUIXUtils.createErrorPage()+Error+number+179761
4/6/17 8:31 PM [STUCK] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneUIXUtils.createErrorPage()+Stack+Trace%3A+%0Aoracle.apps.bne.exception.BneSQLException%3A+Cannot+execute+SQL+Statement.%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.utilities.sql.BneBaseSQL.executeQuery(BneBaseSQL.java%3A1546)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.utilities.sql.BneBaseSQL.getRS(BneBaseSQL.java%3A696)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.webui.control.BneTableUIControl.populateDataSQL(BneTableUIControl.java%3A1377)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.webui.control.BneTableUIControl.populateData(BneTableUIControl.java%3A1184)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.webui.control.BneTableUIControl.createNodes(BneTableUIControl.java%3A1965)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.webui.control.BneLOVUIControl.createNodes(BneLOVUIControl.java%3A766)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.integrator.component.BneAbstractListOfValues.createPage(BneAbstractListOfValues.java%3A736)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.integrator.component.BneAbstractListOfValues.handleComponent(BneAbstractListOfValues.java%3A580)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.integrator.component.BneComponentService.executeComponent(BneComponentService.java%3A512)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.integrator.component.BneComponentService.handleRequest(BneComponentService.java%3A312)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.framework.BneBajaServlet.doRequest(BneBajaServlet.java%3A313)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.bne.framework.BneBaseServlet.doPost(BneBaseServlet.java%3A98)%0A%09at+javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java%3A727)%0A%09at+javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java%3A820)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper%24ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java%3A227)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java%3A125)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java%3A301)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java%3A26)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java%3A60)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.jtf.cabo.interceptor.JTFWrapperFilter.doFilter(JTFWrapperFilter.java%3A149)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java%3A60)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.jtf.base.session.ReleaseResFilter.doFilter(Unknown+Source)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java%3A60)%0A%09at+oracle.apps.fnd.security.AppsServletFilter.doFilter(AppsServletFilter.java%3A432)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java%3A60)%0A%09at+oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter%241.run(JpsAbsFilter.java%3A138)%0A%09at+java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java%3A456)%0A%09at+oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java%3A324)%0A%09at+oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java%3A464)%0A%09at+oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java%3A121)%0A%09at+oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java%3A211)%0A%09at+oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java%3A71)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java%3A60)%0A%09at+oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java%3A163)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java%3A60)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext%24ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java%3A3748)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext%24ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java%3A3714)%0A%09at+weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java%3A321)%0A%09at+weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java%3A120)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java%3A2283)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java%3A2182)%0A%09at+weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java%3A1499)%0A%09at+weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java%3A263)%0A%09at+weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java%3A221)%0A
4/6/17 8:31 PM [STUCK] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneUIXUtils.createErrorPage()+Page%3A+Page%5Bname%3D%5D
4/6/17 8:31 PM [STUCK] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' ERROR          BneUIXUtils.createErrorPage()+Event%3A+PageEvent%5Bname%3Dnull%2Cinterface%3D50001%3AXXPRI_AP_LOAD_INV_XINT_INTF1%2Cbne%3Alayout%3D50001%3ALAYOUT_FCNC6%2Cfield%3AP_SUPPLIER_ID%3D10%2Cintegrator%3D50001%3AXXPRI_AP_LOAD_INV_XINTG%2CtzOffset%3D0%2Cbne%3AdocumentId%3DLU8JD1UUI4WYKKWKPTEZGVTP98T6IVL1CME56UHA%2Cbne%3Alanguage%3DUS%2Cinterface-column-id%3D6%2Cbne%3Acomponent%3D50001%3A_XX_XXPRI_SUP_NUM%2Cbne%3Areporting%3DN%2Cbne%3Alogin_host%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fiebaluvdapp003.primark.local%3A8010%2FOA_HTML%2F%2Cbne%3Acontent%3D50001%3AXXPRI_AP_LOAD_INV_CNT1%2Cbne%3Aviewer%3D231%3AEXCEL2010%2Cbne%3Aembedded%3Dtrue%2Cbne%3Aencoding%3DUTF-8%2Cbne%3Aintegrator%3D50001%3AXXPRI_AP_LOAD_INV_XINTG%2CICX_SESSION_ID%3DfEPRGRSY0O6Y6N1wFMiNn7W4ij%2Cbne%3Apassthru-params%3Dbne%3Aoraclemenu%3DY%26bne%3Alovcontextmenu%3DY%26SUPPLIER_CLASS_TYPE%3DPAYROLL%26SUPPLIER_CODE%3D%2Cbne%3AapiVersion%3D1.1%5D

Any ideas?

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Sorted with a workaround! For some reason the WebADI integrator cannot validate the parameter reference. For this purpose I defined a new field with the logic to filter the suppliers based on the parameter reference. The original old field is hidden and equal to the new field. This way the integrator doesn't have to validate and pass that value to the PL/SQL procedure.

Regards,
Alex